# Deblur an already blurred image (Wiener filter)

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing

I'm trying to do following with an app:

- Blur an image
- Save the blurred image to library
- Open the saved image as deblurred (some loss is acceptable)

As far as I can find on the web, Wiener filter is one of the most common ways of doing that. Is there any way of doing that with swift on ios?

Comment: It sounds like you want to compress the image so it would take less room when stored on the device. If this is your goal i think there are better ways to do lossy compression.

Comment: Nope, my goal is to blur an image and move it as blurred to another device. Later open the image using my app again on the remote device.